# Unwanted Git Repository seen in my github account

Tags: github

I am seeing an unwanted repository in my repository list

Repository Name : `MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs`

1. I have not forked this repository
2. I am not contributor to this repository
3. I am not part of that organization

However I have opened an issue in this project. Is that the reason?

How can I stop this repository appearing ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's a repository you have contributed to recently. As far as I know, the following could count as a contribution :

- you have created an issue on this repo
- you have created a pull request on this repo
- you have reviewed a pull request on this repo
- you have created a commit on this repo

You can get a glimpse of what could be a contribution [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile#what-counts-as-a-contribution)

I didn't found any documentation of what is listed in the repositoy listing when you go to https://github.com. It seems it features :

- repositories you own (user repo)
- repositories you have made a contribution to recently

In your case it seems to be that you've created an issue in the repo. My guess is that it will disappear from your listing after 6 months (from what I've seen myself) if you don't make new contribution to this project anymore

Also, the repositories you have contributed to can be requested via the GraphQL API using this request (from [the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/)):

```graphql
{
  user(login: "forvaidya") {
    repositoriesContributedTo(first: 100, contributionTypes: [ISSUE, COMMIT, PULL_REQUEST, REPOSITORY, PULL_REQUEST_REVIEW]) {
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of the above request seems to request also contributions older than X months (on Github Web UI)