# How to remove an issue from the profile

Tags: github

How can I remove an issue from my profile?
I made an issue in the VSCode repository, and now it is in the
My profile! I've tried everything, but I can't find a way to solve it.

[image: profile]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988020/unwanted-git-repository-seen-in-my-github-account/61991175