# Someone Elses Github Repo showing in my profile

Tags: github

So, I'm new to github. I don't know alot about how things work but today I noticed a repository of someone else popup in my github homepage. I don't know why this happened. I have viewed that repo previously but I have never forked it , cloned it, starred it or watched it. But still for some reason its showing. How do I stop this from happening? [The Marked Repo is the one that I dont want to show in my homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0STXz.png)

Comment: Did you contribute to that repository? This is a list of all repositories you contributed to.

Comment: No I never contributed to it, Not collaborated, Not starred, Not watched or anything. I just visited the repo once last week then it randomly popped in my dashboard.

Comment: Did you maybe open an issue or write a comment?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988020/unwanted-git-repository-seen-in-my-github-account

Comment: @BertrandMartel I have visited that thread and Im very confident that I have not done any of the things listed there that makes it appear in my dashboard

Comment: @Obscure maybe [this PR](https://github.com/bubbl337/RubeGoldberg-HelloWorld/pull/1) made from [this repo](https://github.com/Obscure-Git/Complex-HelloWorld) to [this repo](https://github.com/bubbl337/RubeGoldberg-HelloWorld)

Comment: @BertrandMartel thats not the repo im talking about, the repo im talking about is this [Material-Discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0STXz.png)

Comment: @Obscure https://github.com/CapnKitten/Material-Discord/issues/129

Comment: oh i completey forgot about that, thanks for helping me. but now is there a way to make it dissapear from my dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely because you were given access to them at some point. That's often the case for the list on the left.

Comment: I don't know if its the case but now is it going to stay there forever?

Comment: You can ask to be removed from the repositories in terms of write access.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry for previous comment. I had opened an issue in the repo which I completely forgot about. Thanks for help! :)